# Cannot boot computer in normal or safe mode to run sfc/scannow

Tags: boot, windows-10, sfc

I need to run `sfc/scannow` on my PC. I can get to the command prompt within the recovery options in Windows 10. (when it fails during bootup - the automatic repair GUI). However, I cannot boot successfully in either normal mode or safe mode, so when I run the `sfc/scannow` in the command prompt, it says

```
"Windows resource protection could not perform the requested operation".
```

Through some research, I found that, apparently, if I want to successfully run the sfc, I need to boot into safe mode...but I cannot get into safe mode in the first place. It will fail and the PC will try to do automatic repair again and return me to the screen I first started at.

Is there an alternate way to get into safe mode?

Comment: Are you aware of why your machine is going back to repair? If it was dropped you are relatively out of luck. Consider running chkdsk however.

Answer (score 0):

Which OS is it?  If vista or later, try a restore point.  SFC tends to be more troublesome and less effective that other restoration options.  At the very least you should have a restore point for the most recent round of windows updates.

Also, this is why you need a backup.  Buy an external drive and back up your OS.  Or at least backup your settings and data such that it's no big deal to just rebuild.  Also, learn to capture an iso image of your computer for faster rebuild. /rant

Answer (score 0):

For your review:  How to boot Windows into Safe Mode:
Go to http://support.eset.com/kb2268/
Instructions are there for Windows 7, 8 and 10.

Suggestion:  Unplug your computer, if necessary, to shut completely down ("cold boot").  Or, take the battery out if it's a laptop.  Wait at least 30 seconds.    Then when you plug it back in power up, be sure to tap the appropriate Function key for your OS immediately, every second, over and over again, until it takes you to the choice menu for Safe Mode.  (If you try it during a restart, or power up too soon, the OS starts up so fast, your tapping won't work.)

Another trick I use is to go into the BIOS, scroll over to Boot, and put the C: drive low on the bottom of the boot order list.  Press F10 to Exit and Save.  This allows a little more time for your taps to work.  Later, after success, you can go back into the BIOS, and put C: drive higher up in the boot order where it belongs, usually second to the CD drive if you have one.

Hope this helps you.